# .NET Interpolation calculation?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linear-algebra, interpolation

I'm looking for a slick solution (if it needs to be a .NET Math library so be it) for the following.

I two `DateTime` variables, say `From` and `To`. I also have two numerical values `Start` and `Finish`.

I want to get the value between `Start` and `Finish` at the `At` TimeSpan relative to `From`.

See:

```
//At is the TimeSpan which should be added to From to get the location of the point to be interpolated
GetInterpolatedValue(At, From, To, Start, Finish, InterpolationMethod, Optional InterpolationVars = Nothing)
```

Example:

```
GetInterPolatedValue(TimeSpan.FromDays(1), Now(), Now.AddDays(2), 1, 3, InterpolationMethod.Linear, Nothing)
```

**Should return:** 2

How should I implement this? I just need to be able to interpolate linearly and with a curve (exponential? sorry for my non-algebraic language).

(btw I'm rounding the DateTime / TimeSpan to days)

Comment: Have you looked at this? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation). What do you need help with precisely?

Comment: Maybe it's due to the simple example given, but why do you need both `From` and `To` as well as `Start` and `Finish`?

Comment: @marcind: The difference between `From` and `To` defines the overall timespan which should be taken into account. The return value of the function should be between the the numerical values of `Start` and `Finish`

Comment: @Ani: Yes I looked there. I does not make sense to me. I was hoping to find somebody who can make sense out of it and explain how my problem relates to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I have written something similar over and over again, I first wrote a class containing functions like:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculate the position, of a given value, within a certain range/size
    /// depending on the minimum and maximum (scale) for the value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">Value for which to calculate the position.</param>
    /// <param name="minimum_value">Minimum value of the scale on which the value must lie.</param>
    /// <param name="maximum_value">Maximum value of the scale on which the value must lie.</param>
    /// <param name="size_begin">The begin value of the size on which the scale must be spread.</param>
    /// <param name="size_end">The end value of the size on which the scale must be spread.</param>
    /// <returns>The respectively positions of the data value.</returns>
    static public double Position_In_Size(double data, double minimum_value, double maximum_value, double size_begin, double size_end)
    {
        return size_begin + (((size_end - size_begin) / (maximum_value - minimum_value)) * (data - minimum_value));
    }
```

This quickly became a really big class, in order to support all kind of types. C# doesn't support generics for value types out of the box.

Recently I found a library which implements generics in .NET with a workaround.

Using this library I now have a cleaner implementation. Using a generic interval class, I can 'map' values from one range to another, independant of type.

```
// Result will be 0.
Interval<int> interval = new Interval<int>( 0, 10 );
double result = interval.Map<double>( 5, new Interval<double>( -100, 100 ) );
```

I wrote this as part of some interpolation classes I was working on:
http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/interpolation-no-more/

The source code can be found in my [FCL Extension library](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/fcl-extension/), in the namespace *Whathecode.System.Arithmetic.Range*.

Comment: I keep getting nicer answers :) I'm very interested in looking at your library, I'm leaving you a message!

Comment: Can't leave any message... please send me a messag: theropstah [a] hotmail.com

Comment: Mailed it to you. I will update this post once I make the library open source.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something along the lines of (in pseudocode) `(((At-From)/(To-From)) * (Finish-Start)) + Start`.

Comment: Nice, nice, nice. At which point do I include a variable to add a curve to the 'line'?

Comment: You would need to modify the `((At-From)/(To-From))` section.  That has a range of 0 to 1, so if you square it for example, you'll end up with a non-linear output.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the sample with the test code. It works as you described but without optional parameter. What do you need it for?

```
    private static double GetValueAt(TimeSpan at, DateTime from, DateTime to, double start, double end, Func<TimeSpan, double> function)
    {
        // fullFunction(time) = k *  function(time) + a 
        // k and a are calculated according to start and end values
        TimeSpan totalTime = to - from;
        double k = (end - start) / function(totalTime);
        double a = start - k * function(new TimeSpan(0));
        Func<TimeSpan, double> fullFunction = t => k * function(t) + a;
        return fullFunction(at);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<TimeSpan, double> f1 = t => t.TotalDays;
        Func<TimeSpan, double> fx2 = t => t.TotalDays * 2;
        Func<TimeSpan, double> fsquare = t => Math.Pow(t.TotalDays, 2);

        var f1Value = GetValueAt(TimeSpan.FromDays(1), DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(4), 1, 5, f1); // 2
        var fx2Value = GetValueAt(TimeSpan.FromDays(1), DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(4), 1, 9, fx2); // 3
        var fsquareValue = GetValueAt(TimeSpan.FromDays(1), DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(2), 1, 5, fsquare); // 2
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! I thought I would need an optional parameter somewhere (or multiple) to 'control' the speed of incline/decline of the values produced (with fsquare).